# Get all selected checkboxes and their associated attributes using angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I need to be bundle selected checkboxes together to POST to my server. In each checkbox's attributes, I'm storing some two important values: "pos" (part of speech), and definition. I need to run through each of these checkboxes, push it to a JSON array, and send it off when the "Add Word" button is pressed.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="definition-checkbox" pos="noun" definition="Hill, rolling grassland" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
```

I've thought of turning the checkboxes into element-restricted directives and somehow doing something there, but I'm not sure how to go about getting all the values here, without doing some loop through them all which seems non-Angular.

Any advice?

[image: Prototype]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's difficult to tell where the strings from the `pos` and `definition` attributes come from, but with Angular, you want your views to be a reflection of some data that's accessible on the scope--changes to your view (e.g., checking a box) should change some data on your scope.

In this particular case, I would expect to see the `pos` and `definition` on an object; perhaps the controller has access to an array of them.

```
app.controller('WordController', function($scope) {
  $scope.word = 'property';

  // Maybe this array came from an $http call; maybe it was injected
  // into the page with `ngInit` or `$routeProvider`.
  // The point is, the controller has a client-side representation of
  // the data you want to show *and manipulate* in the view.
  $scope.definitions = [
    { checked: false, pos: 'noun', definition: 'Something that is owned' },
    { checked: false, pos: 'noun', definition: 'A piece of real estate, such as a parcel of land' },
    { checked: false, pos: 'noun', definition: 'real estate; the business of selling houses' },
    { checked: false, pos: 'noun', definition: 'The exclusive right of possessing, enjoying and disposing of a thing' }
    // ...
  ];
});
```

Now that this information is on the scope, you can easily bind to it in your view:

```html
<div ng-repeat='definition in definitions'>
  <input type='checkbox' ng-model='definition.checked'> {{definition.definition}}
</div>
<input type='submit' ng-click='submitDefinitions()' value='Add Word'>
```

Since the checkboxes directly modify the `.checked` attribute of each definition when clicked, the `submitDefinitions` method on the controller can easily determine which definitions were selected:

```
app.controller('WordController', function($scope) {
  // ...

  $scope.submitDefinitions = function() {
    var selectedDefinitions = $scope.definitions.filter(function(def) {
      return def.checked;
    });
    // do something with selected definitions
  };
});
```

Here is a JSFiddle that demonstrates the basic technique: http://jsfiddle.net/BinaryMuse/cTBm4/

Comment: Thanks.  Great solution for simple use cases.